# Issue in updating navigational property in entityframework 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working in entity framework 6.0 , Schema first approach to create database. I have set lazy loading to "false": After creating the database, I am working with Entity (A) i.e Patient, it has navigational property contacts (B). I have changed the contact(B) information of patient(A) for example postcode and then call update on entity A.

```
public static void A(A a)
{
   unitOfWork.ARepository.Update(a);
   unitOfWork.Save();    
}
```

Unit of work Update method code is below

```
public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
{
   dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
   context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;    
}
```

**Any changes in entity A is getting updated to DB but not changes to contact is not getting updated. I am new to entityframework, please guide what needs to be done.**

Comment: You haven't stated what the question is.  What is the actual issue?

Comment: Any changes in entity A is getting updated to DB but not changes to contact is not getting updated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, EF can not be updated navigation property in cases of disconnected entities. You can:

1. Load entity from db then update entity in memory then save changes.
2. Execute sql update script directly into the db.

This issue has long been discussed (you can vote): http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/864

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by disconnected entities ? That the second entity (B) is not loaded into memory ?

Comment: Disconnected entities - entities created in memory and Attached DbContext are not loaded from the database. In general disconnected entities = attached entities.